# APK is not installing in docker emulator

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am trying to install an apk file on my virtual adb resides in a docker container. Whenever I try to install the apk getting the response

> Aborted

The devices listed for the **adb device** command are

> List of devices attached
>
> emulator-5554    device

I endup getting same error for the command **adb -s emulator-5554 install apk_path**. The same is working for some other container and don't have the faintest idea why it is happening so.

Comment: Provide adb devices output please

Comment: List of devices attached
emulator-5554 device